# Using one list with boolean to filter another list

Tags: r, list, filtering

I have 2 lists:

```
>logical.list  
$mask1  
[1] TRUE FALSE TRUE  
$mask2  
[1] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

```
>work.list  
$vector1  
[1] "a" "b" "c"  
$vector2  
[1] "d" "e" "f"
```

I want to use the first one (logical.list) as a mask to extract the next output from work.list:

```
>output.list  
$vector1  
[1] "a" "c"  
$vector2  
[1] "e"
```

Is there an elegant decision avoiding loops, lapply, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract with `Map`.

```
Map(`[`, work.list, logical.list)
# $vector1
# [1] "a" "c"
# 
# $vector2
# [1] "e"
```

---

*Data:*

```
logical.list) <- list(mask1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), mask2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
))
work.list <- list(vector1 = c("a", "b", "c"), vector2 = c("d", "e", "f"))
```

Comment: Seriously? I need to read about the Map function more. Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome @trilisser , You should definitely, use `help('Map')` or `?Map`.